# GPG stub for encryption subkey not working

Tags: encryption, gnupg, smartcard

I created the classical set of authentication, signature, and encryption subkeys with `gpg`, then moved them into a smartcard [ledger nano S], which seemed to work fine as I can see the three subkeys:

```
$ gpg --card-status

  Serial number ....: 00000000
  Signature key ....: F34F 66B8 5D18 A8BC CDD4  C909 4705 D74B 9E2F EFFC
  Encryption key....: AD71 E2C1 2E41 C870 3192  D997 78B9 F3F6 7D9B 47DC
  Authentication key: D644 70D8 88AB BA93 F9F4  BFE0 2726 E1C4 E4DB E4C3
```

### How I landed there

General info:

```
$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27
libgcrypt 1.8.8
```

Generate encryption, signature and authentication subkeys:

```
$ gpg --expert --edit-key Plup*
gpg> addkey
  type: ECC (sign only)
  curve: cv25519
  Please unlock the card

gpg> addkey
  type: ECC (encrypt only)
  curve: cv25519

gpg> addkey
  type: ECC (set your own capabilities)
  allowed actions: Authenticate
  curve: cv25519

gpg> save
```

Check subkeys:

```
$ gpg -K Plup*
sec>  ed25519 2022-06-03 [SC]
      394ED8F3BA05CF4E7866D54657EEBF4BCFF5BFCD
      Card serial no. = 2C97 11BFF50F
uid           [ultimate] Plup* <plup@plup.io>
ssb   ed25519 2022-06-03 [S]
ssb   cv25519 2022-06-03 [E]
ssb   ed25519 2022-06-03 [A]
```

Move the subkeys to a new smartcard slot (`/!\` make sure to not override the master key):

```
$ gpg --card-status
Reader ...........: Ledger Nano S [Nano S] (0001) 00 00
Serial number ....: 7AC3CFF8
Signature key ....: [none]

$ gpg --edit-key Plup*
gpg> key 1
gpg> keytocard
    Signature key
    Passphrase:
    Please entre the Admin PIN
    Number: 2C97 7AC3CFF8

gpg> key 1
gpg> key 2
gpg> keytocard
    Encryption key
    Passphrase:

gpg> key 2
gpg> key 3
gpg> keytocard
    Authentication key
    Passphrase:

gpg> save
```

### The problem I have now

The fingerprints match what the keyring sees, but for some reason I don't understand, the encryption key stub is not in place and the private subkey is still present in the computer keyring. It still asks for the passphrase instead of the smartcard PIN when decrypting:

````
```
$ gpg --with-keygrip --with-subkey-fingerprints -K Plup*

  sec>  ed25519 2022-06-03 [SC]
        394ED8F3BA05CF4E7866D54657EEBF4BCFF5BFCD
        Keygrip = 27D911732841CDB06B3CDFA100DDE95DF420B92E
        Card serial no. = 2C97 11BFF50F
  uid           [ultimate] Plup* <plup@plup.io>
  ssb>  ed25519 2022-06-03 [S]
        F34F66B85D18A8BCCDD4C9094705D74B9E2FEFFC
        Card serial no. = 2C97 7AC3CFF8
        Keygrip = AF76C5E4B1DA101E0F3AFEDDDED6276C4D011261
  ssb   cv25519 2022-06-03 [E]
        AD71E2C12E41C8703192D99778B9F3F67D9B47DC
        Keygrip = E6D65814CBE230A21001F36BD2BC232E6B7251ED
  ssb>  ed25519 2022-06-03 [A]
        D64470D888ABBA93F9F4BFE02726E1C4E4DBE4C3
        Card serial no. = 2C97 7AC3CFF8
        Keygrip = 511C8CAAC3A7B8A2DAD4B3E6A512A7F160A02CD5
```
````

### What I've tried so far

- I've tried to remove the private key and can't force the stub to create itself:

  ```
  ssb#  cv25519/78B9F3F67D9B47DC  created: 2022-06-03  expires: never
  ```
- Launching in debug shows me a wrong keygrip for the key (it keeps creating the same after deletion):

```
2022-06-06 12:47:44 gpg-agent[12064]           id: OPENPGP.2    (grip=C74F8FF13CB491D0C98497C6B77A49FCB156F7E5)
2022-06-06 12:47:44 gpg-agent[12064] DBG: chan_11 -> READKEY OPENPGP.2
2022-06-06 12:47:44 gpg-agent[12064] DBG: chan_11 <- [ 44 20 28 31 30 3a 70 75 62 6c 69 63 2d 6b 65 79 ...(91 byte(s) skipped) ]
2022-06-06 12:47:44 gpg-agent[12064] DBG: chan_11 <- OK
2022-06-06 12:47:44 gpg-agent[12064]           id: OPENPGP.2 - shadow key created
```

Confirmed with:

```
$ gpg-connect-agent 'keyinfo --list' /bye | grep D2760001240103032C977AC3CFF80000

  S KEYINFO 705790B1A7609806F633BCCB212784031E42017E T D2760001240103032C977AC3CFF80000 OPENPGP.1 - - - - -
  S KEYINFO AF76C5E4B1DA101E0F3AFEDDDED6276C4D011261 T D2760001240103032C977AC3CFF80000 OPENPGP.1 - - - - -
  S KEYINFO C74F8FF13CB491D0C98497C6B77A49FCB156F7E5 T D2760001240103032C977AC3CFF80000 OPENPGP.2 - - - - -
  S KEYINFO 511C8CAAC3A7B8A2DAD4B3E6A512A7F160A02CD5 T D2760001240103032C977AC3CFF80000 OPENPGP.3 - - - - -
```

- I tried to recreate a new encryption subkey with the same curve and the `keytocard` still behave the same: it finishes without error but the key (new grip below) is not moved:

```
$ gpg-connect-agent 'keyinfo --list' /bye | grep 5CF6DF65EF080B01F774BCC7F8063814CE5DAEF6
S KEYINFO 5CF6DF65EF080B01F774BCC7F8063814CE5DAEF6 D - - - P - - -
```

Comment: Did you use `keytocard`, as doing so automatically removes the private key from the locally stored main key when doing so?

Comment: Yes I did. But the key was imported and still present in the local keyring. I just set the gpg-agent in debugging and I updated my answer with what seems to be a keygrip collision.

Comment: Can you list all the steps you performed to transfer the keys to the card, as it's likely going to be hard for anyone to replicate this, also including the output of `gpg --version`  _(I've transferred keys to cards quite a few times over the years and have never experienced this; to the contrary, I always export both the main and all subkeys prior to transferring to cards so I have a local encrypted backup of all keys, as `keytocard` [normally] always deletes the private key)_

Comment: Sure. I updated the content with the steps I followed. Strange thing is: I moved the 3 subkeys all in once and only the encryption key failed (silently). I'm wondering if it's not an issue with an unsupported algorithm (although I checked they are all supported on my card).

Comment: @JW0914 It works with another curve. I'll report it. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, using a different curve works:

```
$ gpg -K plup*
sec>  ed25519 2022-06-03 [SC]
      394ED8F3BA05CF4E7866D54657EEBF4BCFF5BFCD
      Card serial no. = 2C97 11BFF50F
uid           [ultimate] Plup* <plup@plup.io>
ssb>  ed25519 2022-06-03 [S]
ssb>  ed25519 2022-06-03 [A]
ssb>  nistp256 2022-06-06 [E]
```

I guess I have to report this to the card provider.